# Using cut efficiently help

Tags: cut-command

I have this command: cut -c 1,9,17,25,33,41,49 data > results
However this is not efficiently written.

Any shorter way to write something similar ?

Thanks

Comment: Some other options here: [How to print every Nth character of a string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612993/how-to-print-every-nth-character-of-a-string)

Comment: It's not necessarily *shorter*, but you could generate the sequence programatically using `seq` ex. `cut -c "$(seq -s, 1 8 49)" data`